# no member named 'wbufferstream' in namespace 'boost::interprocess'

Tags: c++, linux, boost

While compiling a code on CentOS using clang++ version 7, I am getting the following error

no member named 'wbufferstream' in namespace 'boost::interprocess'

I am using boost version 1_66_0

while the same code is perfectly working on windows. Actually I want to use wide buffer stream to handle wide characters on both windows and linux.

fortunately boost::interprocess::wbufferstream is working on windows but not on linux.

Any suggestion??

Comment: Check version of Boost on Linux

Comment: I am using boost version 1_66_0

Comment: Without any codebase from you, I can't say what's wrong with that.